# Rewrite URL on Glassfish with Quercus' PHP

Tags: url-rewriting, glassfish, quercus, question2answer

I have Glassfish 3 server and have added [Quercus 4.0.7](http://quercus.caucho.com/) to to be able to run PHP applications on it. Everything works perfectly with it. Now I'm trying to run [Question2Answer](http://question2answer.org/) application on my server. I was able to open application but it's not allowing me to navigate from page to page because they are using .htaccess file to rewrite the URL. I was wondering how do we rewrite the URL in this case?

Here is what Question2Answer's .htaccess has inside:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /your-sub-directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Do you have any solutions for that?

Comment: Funnily, someone posted almost [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216973/urlrewritefilter-with-glassfish/) a few hours after yours. I think I'm going to flag the other one as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Tuckey's [`UrlRewriteFilter`](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) (which is inspired by [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs-2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and offers similar functionalities) to implement the rewrite rules. Basically, you'll have to:

- Get Quercus's war and unpack it
- Download [the filter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/#download) and unpack it inside Quercus (this will put the filter jar inside `WEB-INF/lib` and the `urlrewrite.xml` under `WEB-INF`).
- Declare the filter in the `web.xml` (see the [install instructions](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/#download)).
- "Port" your rewrite rules to the `urlrewrite.xml` file.
- Repackage and deploy the war (or deploy it as an exploded archive).

The post [Drupal on Glassfish with clean urls using Url Rewrite Filter](http://christianyates.com/blog/glassfish/drupal-glassfish-clean-urls-using-url-rewrite-filter) discusses this approach. Adapt it to your needs.