# how to Hide JSF URL after the application name?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

i have a jsf application and i want hide the url and keep just the name of application in URL while swiching between pages .

thats the url that i have :

```
> http://localhost:8080/PlanificationDrapageWeb/faces/admin/adminHome.xhtml
> http://localhost:8080/PlanificationDrapageWeb/faces/cuisson/Home.xhtml
```

and thats what i want always have :

```
> http://localhost:8080/PlanificationDrapageWeb/
```

how can i get this result ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As MaVRoSCy said you can use Prettyfaces to rewrite your URLs. Their docs are very useful and very clear. Here are steps to follow (without Maven dependencies approach):
1) Download latest jar depending on your JSF version and put it in your project classpath.
2) Add following to `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

3) Create under `WEB-INF` a file: `pretty-config.xml` that will define your prettyfaces mappings, like this one:

```
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.0" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.0
                                    http://ocpsoft.com/xml/ns/prettyfaces/ocpsoft-pretty-faces-3.3.0.xsd">

<url-mapping id="accueil"> 
    <pattern value="/" /> 
       <view-id value="/path-to-yourpage.xhtml" />             
</url-mapping>

<url-mapping id="error"> 
    <pattern value="/" /> 
    <view-id value="/tpath-to-yourpage2.xhtml" />   
</url-mapping>
</pretty-config>
```

4) Now when defining `outcome` in your managed beans, you should return `pretty:idOfURLMapping`. For example: `pretty:accueil` will redirect to the first defined page above and normally it would display `http://localhost:8080/PlanificationDrapageWeb/` as URL.
Finally, notice that you should use this only if it's a functional requirement. Otherwise I would use URLs without extensions as BalusC mentioned (his method or if you want advanced Prettyfaces functionalities).
**EDIT**
It seems that Prettyfaces does not work for this situation. Sorry for your time wasting.
Now I would suggest another possible solution, since BalusC's answer was deleted.
1) You create a new managed bean of session scope, let's call it: `PageManagedBean`:

```
public class PageManagedBean {
  private String includedPage = "/pages/accueil.xhtml";
  //Setters and getters
}
```

2) Create a master layout page (Facelets templating):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>        

<ui:insert name="head"></ui:insert> 
</h:head>
<h:body>  

<div class="pagewidth">
<ui:include src="shared/header.xhtml"/>
<!-- Content -->
<div class="page_content">
    <div class="page_content_inner">
        <div class="container">                
            <ui:include id="pageLivre" src="#{pageManagedBean.includedPage}"/>                  
        </div> 

    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="page_content_footer"/>
 <ui:include src="shared/footer.xhtml"/>
</div>
</h:body>
```

Now when you want to change page, you just change PageManagedBean.includedPage value.

Comment: i got this error when using your solution 
 Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.PrettyConfigListener. Please see server.log for more details.
C:\Users\hp\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PlanificationDrapage\nbproject\build-impl.xml:294: The module has not been deployed.

Comment: @LaabidiRaissi i found your solution interesting but the problem is that the id isn't hide do you have a solution about it

Answer (score 2):

Try using [prettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/).

> PrettyFaces is an OpenSource URL-rewriting library with enhanced
>   support for JavaServer Faces – JSF 1.1, 1.2 and 2.0 – enabling
>   creation of bookmark-able, pretty URLs.

See also this [UrlRewriteFilter with Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216973/urlrewritefilter-with-glassfishfor) a couple ways more on how to do this.

1. Front your GlassFish instance with Apache and use mod_rewrite
2. Use  [Tuckey's Url Rewrite Filter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)

Comment: i found just solution need maven but i am not using maven .. do you have a tutorial to use it with out maven ??

Comment: we cant just add something in web.xml and hide the url ??